# Store result of "ps -ax" for later iterating through it

Tags: linux, shell, sh, posix

When I do

```
ps -ax|grep myApp
```

I get the one line with PID and stuff of my app.

Now, I'ld liked to process the whole result of ps -ax (without grep, so, the full output):

**Either** store it in a variable and grep from it later

**Or** go through the results in a for loop, e.g. like that:

```
for a in $(ps -ax)
do
 echo $a
done
```

Unfortunally, this splits with every space, not with newline as |grep does it.

Any ideas, how I can accomplish one or the other (grep from variable or for loop)?

**Important:** No bash please, only POSIX, so #!/bin/sh

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that while you can't use `$'\n'` is `/bin/sh`, you certainly can still set IFS to contain no characters other than the newline, just by including a newline in your assignment (`IFS='`, a newline literal, then `'`). No reason to play around with  `sed` here.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated above, while loop can be helpful here.
One more useful thing is `--no-headers` argument which makes ps skip the header.
Or - even better - specify the exact columns you need to process, like `ps -o pid,command  --no-header ax`
The overall code would look like

```
processes=`ps --no-headers -o pid,command ax`
echo "$processes" | while read pid command; do
        echo "we have process with pid $pid and command line $command"
done
```

The only downside to this approach is that commands inside while loop will be executed in subshell so if you need to export some var to the parent process you'll have to do it using inter-process communication stuff.

I usually dump the results into temp file created before while loop and read them after the loop is finished.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution by removing the spaces while executing the command:

```
result=$(ps -aux|sed 's/ /_/g')
```

You can also make it more filter friendly by removing duplicated spaces:

```
result=$(ps -aux| tr -s ' '|sed 's/ /_/g')
```

Comment: Note that `result=$(ps -aux)` doesn't split anything at all; it's your `for` loop that does that. If you set `IFS` to contain only the characters you want to split on before the loop enters, there you are.

Comment: That said, a `for` loop isn't well-suited to this task at all; a `while read` loop is more appropriate for reading line-oriented input, and won't require you to change `IFS` from defaults.